# Preposizione di, da o nessuna preposizione dopo il verbo riuscire?

Tags: verbs, grammar, prepositions

Ecco qualche frase:

"non mi riesce farlo"

"Non mi riesce di farlo"

"non mi riesce da fare"

(Qui "questo" è sottinteso)

A me suonano tutte bene, soprattutto se aggiungiamo un avverbio di modo come bene o male alla frasi.

Anche in presenza di proposizioni relative:

"Una cosa che non mi riesce fare"

"Una cosa che non mi riesce di fare"

"Una cosa che non mi riesce da fare"

Non saprei spiegarne i motivi, però avendo qualche dubbio  ed essendo che c'è  gente più preparata sull'argomento, lascio la parola a voi per sapere se sono tutte frasi corrette e se in entrambi i casi ci sono dei motivi dietro alla correttezza/scorrettezza grammaticale di queste frasi.

Grazie in anticipo e buona serata.

Comment: Nakamura, capisco la tua incertezza, ma visto che sei italiano o comunque sai ottimamente l'italiano, hai provato a consultare un dizionario monolingue come il [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riuscire) (cerca “è frequente anche la costruzione mi riesce di fare”) o il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/16?seq=1022) (e pagine seguenti: questo mi rendo conto che è di consultazione un po' più faticosa)?

Comment: Con la preposizione "da", proprio non si può sentire, IMVHO. Potrei capire, anche se la troverei comunque cacofonica, la frase "_una cosa da fare che non mi riesce_", il cui significato è però leggermente diverso da "_una cosa che non mi riesce di fare_"

Answer (score 2):

Le forme seguenti si usano comunemente, sia nella forma scritta che parlata e le reputo corrette:

- non mi riesce di farlo
- non riesco a farlo

Le altre forme citate nella domanda non le ho mai sentite né lette prima. Immagino che siano sbagliate ma anche in questo caso, mi baso sull'esperienza e non ho una regola da citare:

1. non mi riesce farlo
2. non mi riesce da farlo

La 1) è probabile che si senta ogni tanto: un po' di confusione tra "non mi piace farlo" e non "riesco a farlo", dato che entrambe le frasi si dicono in contesti simili e hanno un senso simile.

Comment: “né lette”, con l'accento.

Comment: A me sembra che anche la forma senza alcuna preposizione sia molto comune, soprattutto quando tra "riuscire" ed il verbo successivo c'è un avverbio ("_non mi riesce **facile** farlo_", "_non mi riesce **naturale** parlare in pubblico_")

Comment: Mi sembra che sia però proprio una costruzione diversa, @secan. La costruzione “non mi riesce di fare X” mi pare impersonale, mentre “mi riesce facile fare X” ha come soggetto “fare X”. Sbaglio?

Comment: @DaG non sono sicuro di aver capito il tuo commento: mi sembra che tutte le formulazioni siano costrutti differenti, dal punto di vista grammaticale; anche "non riesco a farlo" è differente da "non mi riesce di farlo". Anzi, nel caso di "riesco a" e "mi riesce di", mi sembra che la differenza sia anche di significato, oltre che grammaticale: "non riesco a farlo" suggerisce una condizione accidentale e transitoria (non riesco in questo momento, non riesco in queste condizioni) mentre "non mi riesce di farlo" suggerisce condizione permanente o comunque prolungata nel tempo (non sono in grado).

Comment: Sì, @secan, scusa la poca chiarezza. Sono d'accordo con tutte le tue considerazioni, ma mi soffermavo specificamente su quelle due costruzioni perché sono apparentemente simili (“mi riesce di fare X”, “mi riesce facile fare X”) ma, come dicevo, credo abbiano una struttura diversa. Poi, senz'altro, “riesco a fare X” è ancora diversa.

Comment: @L.C dire "mi riesce da farlo" è corretto? Mentre "mi riesce da fare" o "mi riesce bene da fare" no? Ho capito bene?

Comment: "mi riesce da farlo" e "mi riesce da fare" NON sono corretti. Si usa "mi riesce di farlo" oppure "riesco a farlo".

Comment: @DaG, scusate se rispolvero questa vecchia discussione.  Avrei ancora  delle incertezze. Ho capito che si può dire: " non mi riesce di farlo", "non mi riesce farlo" e " non mi riesce facile farlo". La preposizione "da" è sbagliata. Sarebbe comunque corretto dire " non mi riesce facile di farlo" sulla base di "non mi riesce di farlo"? Poi, "non mi riesce facile da fare" è corretta? Grazie e scusate se rispolvero questa discussione.